# Assign indices to tiled surface

Tags: arrays

Sorry for my unspecific title (as well as my tags), I just didn't know how to describe that problem in one sentence.

I think its trivial, however my mind is blocked somehow right now.

Some surface is arbitrarliy tiled into smaller subsurfaces (4x4 in this case).
Now I want every subsurface to be assigned an individual index using the width and height of a subsurface (both=9 in this case) and the coordinates Y,Z, so that

```
Index=...Y*Z+Z...?
```

[image]

Comment: ok thx. What about a grid of arbitrary size, say, Y_max * Z_max. Is it then ((Y*Z_max)+Z)*(W*H) ?

Comment: just tried it. It works. Thx. Unfortunately you didn't post an "Answer" which I could accept...